# Javascript dictionary compare

Tags: javascript, dictionary

I got some idea how to speed up my project, but I get stuck at comparing one variable with variables in dictionary and then triggering function. 
My question is, is this possible? And if it is possible, how I can compare it and trigger that function?

```
function Ziskej() {
  var command = document.getElementById("vysledek").innerHTML;
}
for (var i = 0; i < commands.length; i++) {
  if (command === i) {
  }
}
var commands = [
  {
    command: 'hi',
    func: function () {}
  },
  {
    command: 'hello',
    func: function() {}
  }
];
```

Comment: what value you  have in the div with id=vysledek?

Comment: it changes with voice input.
But i already get right answer from Jeremy

Comment: JavaScript does not have dictionaries. Where did you get that term?

Comment: @torazaburo I think it's just a generic term for key-value pairs that people use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
function Ziskej() {
    var command = document.getElementById("vysledek").innerHTML;

    for (var i = 0; i < commands.length; i++) {
        if (commands[i].command == command) {
            commands[i].func();
        }
    }
}

var commands = [{
    command: 'hi',
    func: function() {}
}, {
    command: 'hello',
    func: function() {}
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 (commands.find(el=>el.command===command).func||function(){alert("not found");})();
```

Find the element wich has a command property similar to command, then execute its func. You could use a for loop, like this:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < commands.length; i++) {
      if (command === commands[i].command) {
            commands[i].func();
            break;//stop for loop -> better performance
            //OR
            return; //stop function -> code after the for loop is just executed if nothin found
        }
    }
    alert("not found");//just add if you use return and not break.
```

About speeding up, it would be better to not find, but have such an object:

```
 var commands={
   hi:function(){},
   ok:function(){}
};
```

then you can do:

```
(commands[command]||function(){alert("not found");})();
```

For more explanations read:

=> arrow functions

|| the OR operator ( really cool in js)

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the one-line version will result in an error if no matching array-element is found.

Comment: @DavidThomas i think, implementing error handling was better ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this in ES5:

```
var commands = {
  hi: function() {},
  hello: function() {},
};

// command will be 'hi' or 'hello'
var command = document.getElementById("vysledek").innerHTML;

commands[command]();
```

In ES6:

```
const commandsMap = new Map();
commandsMap.set('hi', function() {});
commandsMap.set('hello', function() {});

// command will be 'hi' or 'hello'
var command = document.getElementById("vysledek").innerHTML;

commands.get(command)();
```

Both these examples eliminate the loop in your function